# Can you suggest how to write this Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge these two tables and want distinct email based on latest execution date(ExecDate)

```sql
WITH cte_1 AS (
        
    SELECT
        Requester_Emails,
        Region,
        ExecDate 
    FROM
        monthly_tickets 
    WHERE
        Region LIKE 'new%' 
        AND
        Region IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION
        
    SELECT
        Requester_Emails,
        Region,
        ExecDate 
    FROM
        weekly_tickets 
    WHERE
        Region LIKE 'new%' 
        AND
        Region IS NOT NULL
),
cte_2 AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cte_1
    ORDER BY
        ExecDate
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT( Requester_Emails ),
    Region
FROM
    cte_2
```

---

Sample input and output data:

[image]

Comment: `Region IS NOT NULL` can be removed. (Only non-null Region values will pass the LIKE condition.)

Comment: Why do you have two different tickets tables?

Comment: Would be easier and more sensible if you just had a ticket table, looks like a bit of a design woops

Comment: `Distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_. `select distinct` will give you distinct _rows_,. Simply write `Select Distinct Requester_Emails, Region from ... ` to make code clearer - for everyone.

Comment: `order by ExecDate` <-- You should not have `ORDER BY` clauses in CTEs or Derived Tables - only the outermost query should have an `ORDER BY`. Most other RDBMS will raise an error but MySQL allows it. It's entirely redundant though.

Comment: _"I want to merge these two tables and want distinct email based on latest execution date(ExecDate)"_ - it's unclear what you're asking. **Please post example desired output data** instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: @Dai there are multiple emails in these two tables and these agents have worked for different regions . I want to find the latest region they have worked ( latest ExecDate )

Comment: @Inavedk Please just show us **example/sample data** instead of trying to describe it in English.

Comment: @Dai I am new to SQL and got to know this that we cant use Order by in CTE's

Comment: @Dai image is attached now

Comment: Please share all clarification (like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output) in text form. This helps others to fiddle around with that data

Comment: @jarlh Thanks got that Not Null point.. i have attached the image to give some more light to the output i want , can you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to do an `INNER JOIN` back onto the initial results.
- DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/araAeTfLPr32Mv636Y7SaJ/0

```sql
WITH ticketsUnion AS (
        
    SELECT
        Requester_Emails,
        Region,
        ExecDate 
    FROM
        monthly_tickets 
    WHERE
        Region LIKE 'new%'
    
    UNION
        
    SELECT
        Requester_Emails,
        Region,
        ExecDate 
    FROM
        weekly_tickets 
    WHERE
        Region LIKE 'new%'
),
latestDateByEmail AS (
    SELECT
        Requester_Emails,
        MAX( ExecDate ) AS maxExecDate
    FROM
        ticketsUnion
    GROUP BY
        Requester_Emails
)
SELECT
    ticketsUnion.Requester_Emails,
    ticketsUnion.Region,
    ticketsUnion.ExecDate
FROM
    latestDateByEmail
    INNER JOIN ticketsUnion ON
        latestDateByEmail.maxExecDate = ticketsUnion.ExecDate
        AND
        latestDateByEmail.Requester_Emails = ticketsUnion.Requester_Emails
ORDER BY
    ticketsUnion.Requester_Emails;
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
With Cte as 
(
    Select Requester_Emails,Region ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Requester_Emails ORDER BY ExecDate) Rn
    from monthly_tickets 
    where  Region  like 'new%' 
   -- and Region IS NOT NULL
union
    Select Requester_Emails,Region ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Requester_Emails ORDER BY ExecDate) Rn
    from weekly_tickets 
    where Region  like 'new%' 
    ---and Region IS NOT NULL 
),

SELECT Requester_Emails,Region FROM cte 
WHERE Rn=1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).